# Unable to access folder directly but can via UNC path

Tags: permissions, network-shares

I am a domain administrator on our network. Recently, I noticed that there was a folder that I was unable to browse directly (when logged on to the server via Remote Desktop) to due to unusual NTFS permissions - although, I could of course make myself the owner then grant myself access if I wanted to.

The strange thing is, leaving the restrictive permissions just as they are, I *am* able to access that same folder via its UNC path (i.e. \\server\share).

How is it possible for a share to provide a higher level of access than directly browsing the same folder when logged onto the server locally? Surely, if anything, a share can only grant the same or *lower* access compared to locally browsing a server?

The server OS is Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

In 2008 R2, you have share permissions and NTFS permissions. You can access these in the Share and Storage Manager MMC snap-in. Because these are seperate, the NTFS permissions set the local file path access, and the share permissions set the share file path access.[image]